# Mysql: converting date fro 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'yyyymmdd'

Tags: mysql, date

Im working on a database that store dates in a `varchar(10)` mysql field (so sad).

I can not alter the database structure (im building a small plug-in), but i have to query the database finding rows where this data field is between the next 10 days.

Example:

```
| fid | fdate      |
|  1  | 10/09/2010 |
|  2  | 17/09/2010 |
|  3  | 19/09/2010 |
```

I have to get the rows with fid 1 and 2, becose the date is <= now + 10 days.

Usually i make this kind of query:

```
SELECT fid FROM table WHERE fdate <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

Or, if the date is in the format `yyyymmdd':

```
SELECT fid FROM table WHERE fdate <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d');
```

But theyre useless with the format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

I've figured out with

```
SELECT fid, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(fdate, 7, 4), SUBSTRING(fdate, 4, 2), SUBSTRING(fdate, 1, 2)) AS mydate FROM table HAVING mydate <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

but i guess it is a bit an overkill rebuilding the date format with concat and substring, and the `having` clause wont help the query speed.

Any idea?

**EDIT**

After Adriano's comment, the right solution is

```
SELECT fid FROM test WHERE STR_TO_DATE(fdate, '%d/%m/%Y') <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

so i can avoid the concat and having clause.

Comment: You can use `where` instead of `having`, but otherwise you appear to have solved the problem-- so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: In the last query i've posted, i cant use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`, becose the field `mydate` doesnt really exists in the table when the `WHERE` clause is executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to create a date from your format?

**EDIT** after reading your comment, I created a table like yours:

```
mysql> SELECT fid, fdate FROM test;
+------+------------+
| fid  | fdate      |
+------+------------+
|    1 | 10/9/2010  | 
|    2 | 17/9/2010  | 
|    3 | 19/09/2010 | 
+------+------------+
```

and then did

```
mysql> SELECT fid FROM test WHERE STR_TO_DATE(fdate, '%d/%m/%Y') <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);
+------+
| fid  |
+------+
|    1 | 
|    2 | 
+------+
```

Seems to work. What exactly do you get?

Comment: Tryed, in the example it works with comma (07,09,2010) but not with slashes (07/09/2010) that's my case...i have then to first replace '/` with `,`, then str_to_date

Comment: The example shows also `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y');` working.

Comment: Oooops youre right, i used to wrote the format wrong, as `%m-%d-%Y` instead of `%m/%d/%Y`! thanks guys